# Impossible to access(display) the image url from Strapi v4 with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I have a problem with Strapi v4, I can not display the image from Strapi.

Here is the data structure in Strapi: [json-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWNzF.png)

I tried to access the image with this source code but in vain : [code-source reactjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCGsI.png)

I get this error : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')**

Please help me, I am new to Strapi

Comment: {posts.length>0?add code here:null }, try this way.

Comment: hopefully, you will fix your error in this way.

Comment: I tried this but nothing is displayed, even the error in the console is not displayed anymore

Comment: can you please share  your code on https://codesandbox.io/ or elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

From the new version of strapi ( Strapi v4), all I had to do was to make the **get request populate** so I could get access to the image :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/articles?populate=*").then((res) => {
      setPosts(res.data);
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are pointing in the wrong url of photos, just try without apiURL, because your images url already deployed in cloudinary

Comment: I receive the same error, someone can examine the structure of the data json, perhaps I am not able to map array that contains an image url, which in itself is in another array.

Comment: try to open with another new tab on the browser, and check if it's working or not, if not you are pointing with wrong url

Comment: same error again !